# Wait for consumer to finish task before others can start

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

I have a Java application that traverses a tree-like folder structure and ultimately deletes the entire folder structure. For this, I am using a `Blocking Queue` with one producer (traverses a tree and puts paths to files that need to be deleted) and a number of consumers that actually perform the delete jobs.

A folder must be empty in order to be deleted, so, consider having the following structure:

```
/folder1/file1
/folder1/file2
/folder1/file3
/folder1/
```

This is what the `BlockingQueue`may contain at any given point. Considering there are 4 consumers polling the queue:

Consumer1 will pick up and delete `/folder1/file1`

Consumer2 will pick up and delete `/folder1/file2`

Consumer3 will pick up and delete `/folder1/file3`

Consumer4 will pick up and delete `/folder1`

---

If Consumer3 did not finish deleting `/folder1/file3`, Consumer4 would not be able to delete `/folder1/` since it will be flagged as non-empty.

Is there a way for the consumer threads to wait other consumer threads to finish certain tasks?

Comment: You could use a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent) per folder which will be initialized with the number of files contains in the folder. The `BlockingQueue` will contains a tuple `(file, countDownLatch)`. If the File is a file, once deleted, the consumer calls `countDown()`, if the File it is a folder, the consumer calls `await()` and then delete the folder.

Comment: Is this your real use case or an analogy ?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot it is a real case. Each folder can contain hundreds of thousands (if not millions) of files/subfolders

Comment: @AdrianDanielCulea Since you are using a tree, focus on deleting the leaves of the tree.

Comment: @boxed__l this is exactly what I am doing (in a single threaded application at the moment). Traversing the tree in a DFS approach and delete every single time I find a file (which is a leaf). Maybe I am missing something from your reply?

Comment: @AdrianDanielCulea if that was the case then the scenario you described wouldn't occur. Correct me if i'm wrong here. Assumption of what you are doing : Until tree is not empty, for each "Iteration", collect all leaves and call the consumer delete code for each leaf.

Comment: @boxed__l since it is a DFS approach, the scenario can (and actually is) happen. Consider a folder containing 2 subfolders, each subfolder containing one file. The algorithm that traverses the tree returns: /root/dir1/file1, /root/dir2/file2, /root/dir1/, /root/dir2/, /root/

Comment: @AdrianDanielCulea Ok got it. So in this case there is also a chance for deadlock right? (depending on your implementation...)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any evidence to support the idea that N threads will be able to delete the files and folders any faster than one thread would be able to do?  Your computer may have several CPUs, but your hard drive probably has just one interface.

Comment: This task runs continuously, 24/7 and it is currently using multi processing to increase performance. The app does not run on my machine and the resources are _unlimited_. A combination of multi processing/multi threading, in theory, should be faster than multi processing only

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve the business problem.

Approach 1 :  Your issue is when Consumer 4 actually gets to Folder, it needs to wait for deletion of all the files. I think Consumer 4 need not have to do that if it have access to the folder1. It can just go to the folder ( operating system path ) and check if it is empty. If empty delete it if not then wait.

Approach 2 :  Your producer thread can do some more work. If it finds that all the files need to be removed in folder1. It need not have to put all the file names and then folder name.  It should just put the folder name.  Only one consumer thread will get the folder name and delete it.

Comment: Very good points, however, Approach 1 is not feasible since all the deletion happen not "on my machine", but in a distributed database, so deleting the metadata that returns the number of files in a folder is deleted by other processes.

Comment: Approach 2 might work, however, if I didn't understand it completely wrong, you are suggesting to traverse the tree with both consumer and producer, which I am trying to avoid building this system

Comment: In Approach 2, I am assuming that if a Consumer Thread delete a Folder then containing files are also deleted. I also assumed that when Producer thread actually put /folder1/file1
/folder1/file2
/folder1/file3
/folder1/     The last Entry is made only when Producer ensure that all the files contained in folder1 are to be deleted.  If so then, producer should not put file1, file2, file3.. It  should just put folder1

Comment: A folder can **never** be deleted (the underlying deletion code from the java driver that interacts with a filler doesn't allow this) if it is not empty

Comment: If Folder can not be deleted before all containing files are deleted. Your consumer thread to delete a Folder can work in following fashion.   Assuming that  Consumer 4 finds Folder1.  Now it will spawn 3 tasks. i.e to delete all 3 files contained in Folder1..  Now since you are submitting all these tasks form Consumer thread 4. So you can wait on Consumer 4  on a Future  to get all child tasks to get complete.

Comment: This is actually a very good approach, however, wouldn't this mean that I will be spawning child threads right from the top of the folder structure (since that is a directory ?) Also, can a **child thread** spawn its own **children threads** ?

Comment: Absolutely.. But you need to be careful though if you are using threadpools for the Consumer Threads.. These new child threads should be on a different threadPool.

Comment: The threadpool should be sized according to your maximum depth + X. If your depth is known and < threshold it is a valid approch

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. I am assuming that the Folder1 will be enqueued after All files from Folder1 are queued.  Here the trick is whenever a Consumer thread picks up the file, change the Thread Name to the File Name. Now when a Consumer Thread (Consumer 4) comes to delete directory Folder1, it will check all the executing threads which have a name "Folder1" on them.  If it finds any, then it will wait for their completion.  I have following code sample for this.. Please let me know in case of any questions

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DeleteFilesAndFolders
{

public void executeSomeTasks() throws InterruptedException
{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    List<DeleteTask> tasks = createSomeDummyTasks();

    for (DeleteTask t : tasks) {
        executor.submit(t);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
}

private List<DeleteTask> createSomeDummyTasks()
{

    List<DeleteTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    tasks.add(new DeleteTask("/good/folder/file1"));
    tasks.add(new DeleteTask("/good/folder/file2"));
    tasks.add(new DeleteTask("/good/folder/file3"));
    tasks.add(new DeleteTask("/good/folder/file4"));
    tasks.add(new DeleteTask("/good/folder/file6"));
    tasks.add(new DeleteTask("/good/folder/file7"));
    tasks.add(new DeleteTask("/good/folder/file9"));
    tasks.add(new DeleteTask("/good/folder/file8"));
    tasks.add(new DeleteTask("/good/folder"));

    return tasks;
}

public static class DeleteTask implements Callable<String>
{

    volatile String fileNameToDelete;

    public DeleteTask(String fileNameToDelete)
    {
        this.fileNameToDelete = fileNameToDelete;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception
    {

        // Just checking if it is a directory
        if (fileNameToDelete.equalsIgnoreCase("/good/folder")) {
            waitForDeletionOfChildFiles(fileNameToDelete);
        }

        String originalName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        Thread.currentThread().setName(fileNameToDelete);
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        Thread.currentThread().setName(originalName);

        return null;
    }

    private void waitForDeletionOfChildFiles(String directoryName) throws InterruptedException
    {
        while (true) {
            Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();

            List<Thread> anyChildThreads = threadSet.stream()
                    .filter(p -> p.getName().contains(directoryName))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            if (!anyChildThreads.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(
                        " Some Child threads still Running. I should be waiting !!");
                anyChildThreads.stream().forEach(x -> {
                    System.out.println(x.getName());
                });

            } else {
                System.out.println(
                        " All Done.. no wait clean this directory !!");
                break;
            }

            Thread.sleep(5000);

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
{
    DeleteFilesAndFolders et = new DeleteFilesAndFolders();
    et.executeSomeTasks();
}

}
```